# String pad center using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, padding, center

I have a string with newlines:

```
character = 'ABC\nDEFGHI\nJKLMNOPQ'
```

I want to do center pad, both of left and right sides having blank spaces.

Is it possible to do this? I need it to print header information in a POS printer.

#### Desired output:

```
       ABC
      DEFGHI
     JKLMNOPQ
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: hii Maheer I edited again my question

Comment: Since the question is closed I'll answer here: ```const padCenter = (str, maxLen) => str.padStart((str.length + maxLen)/2).padEnd(maxLen)```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could

- split the string
- get the max length of all parts
- pad start with the half length and pad end with the max length.

```js
var string = 'ABC\nDEFGHI\nJKLMNOPQ',
    parts = string.split('\n'),
    max = Math.max(...parts.map(({ length }) => length));

parts = parts.map(s => s
    .padStart(s.length + Math.floor((max - s.length) / 2), ' ')
    .padEnd(max, ' ')
);

console.log(parts.join('\n'));
```